# The best AutoCAD 2010 Ubuntu alternative?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, cad

I'm looking for the best AutoCAD 2010 alternative for Ubuntu. Wine's support for the 2010 version isn't polished so I'm looking for Linux based similar programs.

I know that this can be subjective so I'd like to know what's the best Ubuntu alternative which has the most similar, and significant features as that of AutoCAD 2010? I'm not familiar with the program because I'm researching this for my sister who is studying Aeronautical Engineering.

Any help is appreciated.

I'm using 12.04 64-bit on my ThinkPad R61i with 3.8GB memory and 160GB hard drive.

Comment: For Aeronautics, check out openVSP (Vehicle Sketch Pad), the NASA open source parametric geometry program.  It's a bit of a pain to set up for Linux, but possible -- check out the Linux instructions at http://www.openvsp.org/wiki/doku.php?id=install

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[LibreCad](http://librecad.org/cms/home.html) is good I use it myself but to be honest you will struggle to find one as good as AutoCad. When you pay the kind of money that Autocad costs who wouldn't want something extra special.

Answer (score 9):

In the free but commercial category, DraftSight is the only native software running on Ubuntu compatible with DWG files - it's 2D only (can view 3D files but not create them), sort of an equivalent to AutoCAD LT. Its native format is DWG v2010.

If you're willing to pay Bricscad is a lot more powerful, has ACIS modeling just like AutoCAD (Pro version) and its Platinum version has even parametric modeling. All that for a fraction of the price of an AutoCAD license.

But in any case, I'm not sure AutoCAD is suitable for aeronautical engineering...

Comment: Draftsight is very close to Autodesk Autocad, I have a very good use of it